# How to develop web sockets in worklight

Tags: websocket, ibm-mobilefirst

I have an android application developed with IBM Worklight, in which a html file is making http request every 5 seconds and fetching the data from the server. Now I wish to replace this with HTML5 web sockets. But I wish to use the Worklight capabilities.

1. Is there anything like HTTP Adapter in Worklight for web socket?
2. If not could anyone please give any pointer about how to achieve it in worklight?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything like HTTP Adapter in Worklight for web socket?

No. At least to the best of my knowledge.

> If not could anyone please give any pointer about how to achieve it in
>   worklight?

Web Sockets are not supported on Android (2.1-4.2): http://caniuse.com/#search=web%20sockets

However, you can try a Cordova Plugin like [WebSocket-for-Android](https://github.com/knowledgecode/WebSocket-for-Android). There's a blog post that may help [here](http://opensourcesoftwareandme.blogspot.com/2012/07/web-socket-cordova-plugin-for-android.html#.UbiJNGTF0aA). I just got those links for a quick [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=web+socket+cordova+plugin).

Comment: WebSocket is not an out of box feature of worklight. In order to develop web socket in worklight I wrote my own web socket and put it in <TOMCAT_HOME>/webapps/worklight/WEB-INF/classes/ folder and put an entry in the <TOMCAT_HOME>/webapps/worklight/WEB-INF/web.xml. We can develop a separate web project and write our web socket there.